# Css Change color of element by click on the other element

Tags: html, css

I have pagination
How can I change background of `pagination__link` with text "left" when click on the other links? It is necessary to use  only CSS.

Comment: you can't do this in css alone.. Manipulating the DOM is the role of javascript..

Comment: Why limit yourself? jquery not that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but frankly it's messy, using CSS flexible-boxes along with the relatively new `:focus-within` pseudo-class. This does require reversing the order of `<li>` elements within the `<ul>` however:

```js
.pagination {
  /* sets the display to use the flex layout: */
  display: flex;
  /* ensures the contents of the <ul> are shown in
     columns and in reverse-order: */
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

/* selects first the <li> that has a focused element
   within it, then finds all subsequent <li> elements,
   using the general-sibling combinator ('~') that
   also matches the :last-child pseudo-class (there can,
   obviously, be only one) then finds the <a> element(s)
   which is a child of that <li> element: */
li:focus-within ~ li:last-child > a {
  background - color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="pagination__item pagination__item--active">
    <a class="pagination__link" href="#">
      Page 2
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="pagination__item">
    <a class="pagination__link" href="#">
      Page 1
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="pagination__item">
    <a class="pagination__link" href="#">
          left
        </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[External JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ogeehwya/).

References:

- [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within).
- [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).
- [General Sibling Combinator (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)
- "[Using CSS Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)" (MDN).

Comment: Is it posiible if I add one more li at the end as "right" to do  highlighting in both directions - left and right at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[name="radio"]{
  display: none;
}
label{
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}

input[name="radio"]:checked + label{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="pagination__item">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" />
    <label for="radio1">left</label>
    <!--
    <a class="pagination__link" href="#">  
      left
    </a>
    -->
  </li>
  <li class="pagination__item">
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" />
    <label for="radio2">Page1</label>
    <!--
    <a class="pagination__link" href="#">
      Page 1
    </a>
    -->
  </li>
  <li class="pagination__item pagination__item--active">
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" />
    <label for="radio3">Page1</label>
    <!--
    <a class="pagination__link" href="#">
      Page 2
    </a>
    -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Maybe it's not the answer what you want.

But I think it can be good hint for your problem.

You can use the checkbox trick or radio trick.